# My python code for converting binary values to decimal is not working as I want

Tags: python

```
 binary=input('Please, enter the binary value: ')
 power=len(binary)-1
 denary=0
 for x in binary:
    denary=denary+(int(x)*(2^power))
    power=power-1
    if power<0:
        break
 print (denary)
```

I tried to write a code in python that converts binary values to decimal but the code isn't working properly, not all outputs are correct. Can someone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Please add a few example inputs, along with the incorrect values this code generates and the correct values your code should generate.

Comment: note that there is an optional second parameter that can be passed to `int` to specify the base, e.g: `int('11', 2)` gives 3

Comment: Also thank you Sam, your way is much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the "raise to the power" operator is `**`, not `^`:

```
denary=denary+(int(x)*(2**power))
```

`^` is the 'exclusive OR' operator.